# Random Text Grid Generator in Animation Node?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, animation-nodes, procedural

Is it possible to create a random text object for each vertex of a grid mesh?

Comment: Is there any reason it has to be in animation nodes? It's rather simple if you use python.

Answer (score 2):

- Generate a list of all possible texts. (We can skip this if the texts are completely random)
- Create a random list of the same length as the vertices in the grid.
- Instance `n` number of text objects where `n` is the length of the vertices list.
- Set the texts to the text objects.
- Position the objects.

[image: Node Tree]